# How to integrate Amazon SES Account with MailChimp STS plugin?

Tags: plugin-mailchimp

I'm trying to set up the plugin MailChimp. I have uploaded the plugin and installed it. (https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mailchimp-sts/) The directions tell me I will need

1. MailChimp account and API key (done)
2. Amazon SES account with production access (I have signed up
   with Amazon)
3. Verified email address to sue as sender (got it)

The only place on the form to do anything is the blank next to "API key". I've cut and pasted in the key number given me.

Now all I get is "API error. Please setup the integration first".

How do I go about setting up the integration?

Answer (score 1):

This part can't be done in plugin, it should be done in your MailChimp account. Please see `readme.html` file supplied with plugin, section `4. Integrate Amazon SES with MailChimp`.

[image]

**Update** As per [our discussion elsewhere](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-mailchimp-sts-integrate-amazon-ses-account-with-mailchimp) you need paid MailChimp account for SES integration option to be active.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot,

I have read it. And I'm block at the 6. section :

    Configure and test plugin.

=> input and save your MailChimp API key in plugin's settings;

Answer (score -3):

Try this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amazon-ses-and-dkim-mailer/

Comment: How does this answer question?